# Job recomendations not relevant for contractors

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Job Recommendations are allegedly *"Based on your experience, interests, and preferences."*. However I'm a contractor getting suggestions about permanent positions. How can I filter out these perms?

Here in the UK it's considered a very annoying practice to call a contractor about a perm job. I understand in other countries people don't even understand what exactly a contract role is and that might be the reason why there is no filter.

Comment: Let's just exerminate the permies, (and maybe some agencies too:)

Comment: There is an option that allows you to indicate what types of jobs you're interested in [in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current). Do you have anything but "Contract" checked there?

Comment: @CodyGray, Yes, only contract is ticked and haven't change these settings for a quite time. I still get perm ads unless I say not looking for job, or not actively looking.